# How to print the name of corresponding value of select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

We can print the value of select option using
document.querySelector(".choose").value;  but I need the name of it's corresponding value
Ex: If the value of select is "VAR CHAR" but you need to print the name as text

```html
<select name='choose' class='choose'>
  <option name='text'>VAR CHAR</option>
  <option name='number'>NUMBER</option>
  <option name='radio'>RADIO</option>
  <option name='checkbox'>CHECK BOX</option>
  <option name='email'>EMAIL</option>
  <option name='file'>FILE</option>
  <option name='date'>DATE</option>
  <option name='password'>PASSWORD</option>
  <option name='range'>RANGE</option>
  <option name='tel'>TELEPHONE</option>
  <option name='submit'>SUBMIT</option>
  <option name='button'>BUTTON</option>
  <option name='reset'>RESET</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why not save it as `value` attribute instead of `name`

Comment: Glad it helped, upvote will be appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

You select element has a class by the name of "choose" and you can use the following code which was written by jquery.

```
$('.choose').on('change', function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    name = selectedOption.attr('name');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just tried something..

```
document.querySelector('.choose').selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you know how to select the element already. Now all you need to do is

```
var name = element.getAttribute("name");
```

and then print it.